# Updatte SensorManager TYPE_ORIENTATION to getOrientation()

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-sensors

I have a old plugin of cordova that get the device orientation.
But this old way does not work with some new devices

```
 /**
 * Start listening for compass sensor.
 *
 * @return          status of listener
 */
public int start() {

    // If already starting or running, then just return
    if ((this.status == CompassListener.RUNNING) || (this.status == CompassListener.STARTING)) {
        return this.status;
    }

    // Get compass sensor from sensor manager
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    List<Sensor> list = this.sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

    // If found, then register as listener
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        this.mSensor = list.get(0);
        this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        this.lastAccessTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.setStatus(CompassListener.STARTING);
    }

    // If error, then set status to error
    else {
        this.setStatus(CompassListener.ERROR_FAILED_TO_START);
    }

    return this.status;
}


 /**
 * Sensor listener event.
 *
 * @param SensorEvent event
 */
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // We only care about the orientation as far as it refers to Magnetic North
    float[] orientation = event.values;

    // Save heading
    this.timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.setStatus(CompassListener.RUNNING);

    // If heading hasn't been read for TIMEOUT time, then turn off compass sensor to save power
    if ((this.timeStamp - this.lastAccessTime) > this.TIMEOUT) {
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

My question is how can i update this to the new way sensor.getOrientation() ?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, orientation here refers to compass orientation and NOT screenOrientation (i.e. landscape vs portrait)?

Comment: @Mister_CK yes compas

Answer (score 1):

I think this PR should have the changes you are looking for (it is not mine): https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/pull/78
In the issues someone also says they created a fork that resolves the issue.